# VLC closes immediately when playing file accessed in the file manager

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, vlc

This problem didn't appear immediately after installing VLC from repos in Kubuntu 18.04, but after a while.

- Starting VLC and using its internal GUI actions (Open file etc) works.
- Running `vlc path/to/file` works.
- ***After setting VLC as default for a file type and executing it or using "Open with" from Dolphin's context menu, VLC starts but closes immediately.***
- If VLC is **already running** when executing a file or using "Open with" from Dolphin's context menu, the file is played as expected.

Comment: Did you tried to clear VLC's configuration by removing `~/.config/vlc` ? And the same for cache - `~/.cache/vlc` and `~/.local/share/vlc`.

Comment: @N0rbert - so simple. I simply forgot vlc is a program like any other. :) removing `~/.config/vlc` was enough. Would you care posting as answer.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can recommend to clear VLC's folders, such as

- `~/.config/vlc`
- `~/.cache/vlc`
- `~/.local/share/vlc`

Comment: I can also add that after solving as indicated, another problem was also fixed: that of not being able to run a VLC AppImage file from a `.desktop` file.

Comment: This also worked perfectly for me after I updated to Kubuntu Groovy Gorilla. AFAIR the same happened with a previous version update.

Comment: Have the same issue in Kubuntu 20.04, but could not resolve it with the approach suggested here. I guess the issue lies a bit deeper :-(